# R package for analyzing Duplication, Transfer, and Loss (DTL) reconciliations?

Tags: r

I have a species tree (16S) and a gene tree (Rubisco large subunit) and I would like to import these into R and preform Duplication, Transfer, and Loss (DTL) reconciliations. I have found a software program called eMPRess that does a similar analysis to DTL, but in the context of host/parasite interactions. It good for a quick pass analysis, but its GUI interface is very limited for what I need. I am wondering if there is an R package out there that allows this type of analysis? Any advice?